# How to add a callback to a form submit when AJAX is not an option (e.g., for a file download)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, asynccallback

I need to add a callback to a jQuery form submit that will be called after the request completes (something like `.complete` on an AJAX request). I know that there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11534690/21255), but there's currently nothing there that works for my needs. I have a form submit that initiates a file download, so by its very nature, I can't use an AJAX request; it has to be a form submit. Is there any way that I can get the file download and have a callback called once the request completes (whether successfully or otherwise)?

I've also investigated the possibility of wrapping the form submit in a promise; but that requires the ability to pass in success/failure callbacks in the first place.

(There's also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39083815/21255), which doesn't have an answer.)